# In-App Purchase - Available Products do not have a localizedTitle, localizedDescription

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I have 1 IAP that has been submitted w/ the app for review.
When i retrieve available list of products (just 1 at this time) I do see the submitted IAP product. So far so good.

Now when it comes down to showing the product (in a `UITableView`), the `localizedTitle` and `Description` properties are empty.

*** Question ***
Why is the displayable product info empty?

I am following this [raywenderlich's in-app-purchase-tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial).

*** Updated ***

After request the list of projects, i print out the retrieved list.
I am printing out each product like this:

```
for p in products {
  print("Found product: \(p.productIdentifier) \(p.localizedTitle) \(p.price.floatValue)")
}
```

Interestingly i see the productIdentifier and price printed out. But there is no localizedTitle (it is just empty string).

Comment: Did you add the other language in the _localisations_ section of the IAP and provide Display Name and Description in that language?

Comment: Adeel. Yes, but only for English (U.S.).

Comment: Could this mean that my simulator (or my device) are not configured to English (U.S.)? That's the only thing I can think of. Otherwise I'm at a loss for words.

Comment: don't you have to add a different IAP for each language that you want to support.. when you added an IAP you selected English as the language, I don't think your localizedTitle will change that I think you need a new IAP for each language with a translated title for each. Just an idea, I'm not 100% sure on that

Comment: MSU_Bulldog. Iam only concerned about English right now.

Comment: "Could this mean that my simulator (or my device) are not configured to English " <<--- I would think this is a possibility if your simulator is not configured for english.  If you're developing w/a different language on the simulator, try adding a localization in that language.

Comment: I also facing same issue, i tried to change apple ids country, device language, but did not work, did anyone find solution.

Comment: I've only one localization and I'm getting empty titles since yesterday. It was working fine until then. Don't know what happened.

Answer (score 0):

In simulator settings, set the language to "English (U.S.)":

- Settings App -> General -> Language & Region -> iPhone Language

[image]

It defaults to the first of "Preferred Languages" in your OSXs "System Preferences":

[image]

Comment: But what is the explanation for this happening on the physical iPhone device?

Comment: The same is true for devices.

Comment: I have same problem. I configured my computer and my iPhone to Turkish but i didn't work when i run app. Also i added Turkish language to Configuration.storekit